# Running a console command produces an error mentioning sessions. How do I resolve?

Tags: console

None of the craft core console commands to work.
For example: `./yiic querygen all My_MyRecord` produces an error which includes mention of `session`?

How do I get craft console commands working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a plugin which is listening to the `userSession.onLogin` event and trying to access the current user from the session.

The solution is for the plugin developer to wrap the event listener to ignore console sessions like this:

```
    if(!craft()->isConsole())
    {
        craft()->on('userSession.onLogin',
            [
                craft()->market_customer,
                'loginHandler'
            ]
        );
    }
```